# Angular 5 with Material 2 - Png images not loading with proper directory?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to load in 4 png images of various social media icons. And they're located in the same directory as where the background I'm using is, and i'm referring to them both in the same way with ../../images/[image] but the png images are not being recognized correctly and the jpg that's being loaded in the CSS is. I have absolutely zero clue as to why this would be occuring

CSS:

```
.sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../../images/background.jpg");
}

.app-content {
  padding: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 84px);
}

mat-card {
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.themathon-text {
  background-color: rgba(42,42,42,.7);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [class.app-dark-theme]="true">
    <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen class="sidenav-container">
        <!-- The Navigation button at the top of the application -->
        <mat-toolbar class="toolbar">

            <div class="select-discord" (click)="navigateToDiscord()">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> Discord
            </div>

            <div class="select-twitch" (click)="navigateToTwitch()">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> Twitch
            </div>

            <div class="select-twitter" (click)="navigateToTwitter()">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> Twitter
            </div>

            <div class="select-youtube" (click)="navigateToYoutube()">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> YouTube
            </div>

        </mat-toolbar>

        <!-- Main content of the website -->
        <div class="app-content">

            <img src="../../images/discord.png" alt="Discord">
            <img src="../../images/twitch.png" alt="Twitch">
            <img src="../../images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
            <img src="../../images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube">

            <mat-card class="themathon-text">

                It's that time of the year again! <br>

                The doors for the Themeathon Pre-Marathon submissions are now open!<br>

                A marathon to help raise funds for equipment and other expenses to help 
                run the actual Themeathon event in Autumn this year.<br>

                Make sure to submit your games over on this website!<br>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>

            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

File Structure:

the css and html are app.component.css and app.component.html

[image]

Debugger:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your `angular-cli.json` There you can specify a path for your assets folder:
By default, the `src/assets/` folder and `src/favicon.ico` are copied over. so you need to add images.

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "images",
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

then you can also just use `/images/` for your links